# How convert the output of "ps" and "head" to JSON with key "{#PROCNAME}"?

Tags: ps, json, zabbix

I'm trying to get a JSON document with the top 5 processes by memory.

This JSON I want to send to Zabbix and draw the top 5 processes by memory.

I get the top 5 processes by memory by the following command:

```
ps axho comm --sort -rss | head -5
node
mongod
kubelet
dockerd
systemd-journal
```

How to convert the output of `ps`+`head` to JSON with key `{#PROCNAME}` to get this structure:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{#PROCNAME}": "node"
    },
    {
      "{#PROCNAME}": "mongod"
    },
    {
      "{#PROCNAME}": "kubelet"
    },
    {
      "{#PROCNAME}": "dockerd"
    },
    {
      "{#PROCNAME}": "systemd-journal"
    }
  ]
}
```

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/macros/lld_macros

There is a type of macro used within the low-level discovery (LLD) function:

```
{#MACRO}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `jq` has the `inputs` function, and assuming `{#PROCNAME}` is just a string, you can use the following:

```
ps axho comm --sort -rss | head -5 | jq -Rn '{data: [inputs|{"#PROCNAME":.}]}'
```

The `inputs` functions lets `jq` read all input string. The rest is decoration to get the wanted format.

The option `-R` gets raw string as input.
The option `-n` feeds `jq` input with `null` entry. That way `inputs` gets all strings at once.

Comment: Thanks! Changed: ps axho comm --sort -rss | head -5 | jq -Rn '{data: [inputs|{"{#PROCNAME}":.}]}'

Comment: @AntonPatsev Yes you're right. It was a typo...

Answer (score 1):

actually, you could achieve it with just standard unix cli:

```
bash $ echo { \"data\": [  $(ps axho comm --sort -rss | head -5 | xargs -L1 -I% echo { \"{#PROCNAME}\": \"%\" } | paste -s -d, -) ] }
{ "data": [ { "{#PROCNAME}": "node" },{ "{#PROCNAME}": "mongod" },{ "{#PROCNAME}": "kubelet" },{ "{#PROCNAME}": "dockerd" },{ "{#PROCNAME}": "systemd-journal" } ] }
bash $
```

- the resulting output is a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [oliv's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503135/116858), but moves the `head` operation into `jq`:

```bash
ps axho comm --sort -rss |
jq -Rn '[inputs][:5] | { data: map({ "{#PROCNAME}": . }) }'
```

The first part, `[inputs][:5]`, extracts the five first lines from the output of `ps` as an array, and the second part inserts this array as the value of `data`, with each of its elements converted into a separate object with a `{#PROCNAME}` key.